# Having issues making my diagonal lines connect

Tags: css

I'm trying to use http://patternify.com to try to make diagonal lines, it's working but the lines don't seem to be connecting, this is how they show up:

[image]

If you look closely you'll see small gaps between where the lines meet.

This is the link to the pattern generator http://ptrn.it/1TonkQe

Any information on how to make these lines connect or a better way to do it would be great thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use diagonal line from [patternify](http://www.patternify.com/) copy the css code [from here](http://www.patternify.com/#%7B%22matrix%22:[%C4%8A%2266%22,%C4%8C%C4%8E%C4%90%C4%8D%C4%8F1],[%C4%91%C4%8F%C4%9A%C4%93%C4%92%C4%96%C4%98%C4%9C%C4%A1%C4%94,%C4%9F%C4%99%C4%A3%C4%A2%C4%9E%C4%97%C4%A6%C4%92%C4%A8%C4%95%C4%AA%C4%AD%C4%9D%C4%AE%C4%A0%C4%A7%C4%B4%C4%A9%C4%B3%C4%AC%C4%B5%C4%B2%C4%AB%C4%9B%C4%B9%C4%A4%C4%AF0%C4%9B%C5%80%C4%90%C5%820.8]%C4%AA%C4%BB%C4%B1%C5%8B%C4%A5%C4%B0%C4%9C%C5%8D%C4%BD%C5%8F%C4%AF%C5%91%C4%A3%C5%90%C4%B8%C5%97%C4%BA%C5%8E%C5%95%C5%93%C5%98%C5%8C%C5%9C%C4%BC%C5%9D%C5%8D%C5%82%22%C5%A3%C5%84%C5%86%C5%9F%C5%8B%C5%92%C5%89%C5%9A%C4%B6%C5%8A%C4%B0%C5%96%C5%A0%C5%B1%C4%BE%C4%B7%C5%B2%C5%92%C5%B4%C5%A9%C5%9B%C5%B7%C5%AF%C5%A8%C5%BB%C4%A0%C5%A5%C5%81%C4%8F%C5%85%C5%87%C5%BA%C4%BD%C5%B0%C5%B8%C4%A9%C5%AB%C5%94%C5%AD%C5%AC%C5%99%C6%8A%C6%8D%C5%9D%C5%B6%C5%AE%C6%85%C5%BC%C6%93%C5%BE%C6%80%C5%83%C6%81%C5%A7%C6%84%C5%A1%C6%94%C6%9C%C6%9B%C5%B2%C4%96%C6%89%C6%90%C5%B9%C6%92%C6%9E%C6%A5%C6%A0%C6%9D%C6%A8%C6%9F%C5%9E%C6%96%C6%98%C6%AE%C6%82%C6%A9%C6%AC%C6%A7%C6%B2%C6%8C%C5%B3%C6%B3%C5%AA%C4%98%C6%B7%C6%A4%C6%B5%C6%86%C5%BD%C6%BA%C6%8B%C5%BF%C6%AF%C6%9A%C6%BF%C6%8F%C5%B5%C6%BB%C6%8E%C6%B6%C6%BC%C6%B1%C6%B8%C4%8B%C7%88%C6%BD%C6%95%C7%84%C7%89%C7%81%C5%A4%C6%99%C6%83%C7%91%C7%8F%C6%A6%C7%8A%C6%AB%C6%91%C7%9A%C7%97%C5%88%C6%B9%C7%9D%C7%A1%C7%93%C5%A6%C7%96%C7%A1%C7%8E%C7%8B%C7%87%C6%A3%C6%8B%C7%A7%C7%9B%C7%A9%C7%86%C6%88%C7%A0%C7%AC%C4%99%C7%A3%C7%95%C7%A8%C7%AB%C7%AA%C7%85%C6%87%C7%B9%C6%BE%C7%A6%C7%B8%C7%89%C7%B2%C7%8A%C5%AB%C7%B4,%C6%B0%C7%AD%C7%B7%C7%AF%C7%BB%C7%90%C7%BD%C8%88%C7%BF%C7%BE%C7%98%C6%AA%C7%9E%C8%86%C4%AE%C7%9F%22xcursor%C4%8810%C4%90y%C8%97%C8%99%C8%9B%C8%9D0%7D) and use as below.

HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.myDiv{
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAO0lEQVQYlY3KuREAIAwEsatt66cnkwDD44dAmQRYRVLTTwIsjTOlcU9hvJMbvfTEKB0xSytWaZw6AdYBgzinO79RFiIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I just got the same result as you, I am not a fan of those css generator tools. This is how I create css diagonal stripes: https://jsfiddle.net/d4f3y92h/1/

```
body{
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%,
                  transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
                  transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```